# How to make delay 1 second before execute some function?

Tags: flutter

I have some question about my code. Before that, I want to create delay 1 second before executing some function I create. Here is my code:

```
Widget setProfile() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _sessionBloc.sessionLogin,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == 200) {
          return profileUser();
        } else {
          return notSignIn();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Code above means if `snapshot have data like 200`, it will show widget `profileUser()`, but if `snapshot doesn't have data`, it will show widget `notSignIn()`. But I want this data to have flow like this:

> First, before hitting this function or get data, it will show some widget
>   like loading widget for 1 second, then it will run first `if` or to
>   `else`.

You may ask, why should it be like that?

In fact, I have some data in [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) like `status` with type `int`. I know that shared preferences is a local, but when I get one data as `status` with value is 200. It shows delayed in a millisecond, it's like flashing. I don't know why it happened. Already ask it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499174/why-get-data-from-shared-preferences-have-a-delayed/57513472#57513472) but don't have a solution. So, finally, I decided to overcome this by adding a delay of 1 second and bring up some widget as I asked above. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't checking for the `ConnectionState`.  The example at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html will show you how to display an intermediate message while the Stream is still loading.